# Add windows to my boot menu

Tags: grub2, windows

I have windows installed on /dev/sda3 and running Ubuntu 11.10 on /dev/sda5. The boot loader points to /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2. Both are parts of the recovery system for my laptop.

How do I edit the boot menu so that it points to /dev/sda3. I've tried following the directions, but I'm confused by them and many are outdated as things changed, apparently with 11.04.

Can someone help me, please? I just need to add the one entry.

Thanks!

It turns out that /dev/sda2 was my windows loader, but it was failing to boot. After a helpful comment (in an answer below), I re-installed windows and it fixed the issue. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that /dev/sda2 was my windows loader, but it was failing to boot. After a helpful content, I re-installed windows and it fixed the issue. thanks for the help

Answer (score 9):

`update-grub` should automatically detect and add Windows partitions.  What's the output of this command?

This page is long, but the directions here should work for adding a custom menu entry:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

It would be something like:

```
menuentry "Windows" {
set root=(hd0,2)
chainloader +1
}
```

You might need to twiddle the numbers to get the right partition.

Comment: Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
done

It once again missed windows on /dev/sda3

Comment: Are you really sure that the Windows 7 bootloader is on sda3?  Even if sda3 is your NTFS partition with Windows, the bootloader might be on sda2.

Comment: @Thom Please add that information to your original question, that way it's not buried in a comment!

Answer (score 0):

my Grub.cfg for win on **/dev/sda3**

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-1592F8230DB28FD2' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,msdos3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  1592F8230DB28FD2
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1592F8230DB28FD2
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
chainloader +1
```

}

or insert cd/usb **ubuntu_live** and start ubuntu_Live then start "**Gparted**" 
after open Gparted , Ritht click on **partition** that install ubuntu and change **Flag** to "**Boot**"
after reboot you run from Ubuntu then into terminal type **"update-grub"**