# trying to install 12.10 does not have option to run alongside of windows, i have 444780 MB of shrink space

Tags: installation, windows, partitioning

Windows says i can shrink the space. Should i use their option or is that too risky also will this change allow me to run ubuntu alongside of windows?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Whatever you do do not shrink space without checking you are running alongside! I'll try finding a question which could help you out.

Comment: Here's the question I had in mind, you probably have 4 partitions [question on not having run alongside windows option](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229759/ubuntu-12-10-windows-7-no-option-to-install-alongside-windows-7) this should answer your question so I'm flagging yours for closure, though if you need more help just ask a new question saying that you've already read that one, hope it helps :)

Comment: If you find [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229759/ubuntu-12-10-windows-7-no-option-to-install-alongside-windows-7) doesn't solve your problem, please expand this question with details. (If we've already closed this as a duplicate when you do that, you can comment to request this be unduped/reopened, *after* expanding your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the shrink option. It works fine. Leave space for windows, too. It will need it for updates. Then, use the disk to install Ubuntu in the free space. You can also create an extended partition with a linux primary partition and swap primary partition inside it. Then create an ext3 file system. Then install Ubuntu. That shrink space is about 400 GB. You need about 20 GB for Ubuntu. You can probably get away with 100 GB of shrink space. Windows updates are huge.