# Does not give me the option to run alongside another operating system

Tags: installation

During installation it does not give me the option to "run alongside windows" instead the pop up box gives these options:

1. ERASE DISC
2. ENCRYPT THE NEW UBUNTU INSTALLATION
3. USE LVM
4. SOMETHING ELSE

really am quite new at this and dont know how to manually partition or attach root files which is what the "SOMETHING ELSE" choice does.

Everyone I have talked to and the Ubuntu manual says it gives you a choice to "run alongside windows", does anyone know how to remedy this problem?

Comment: take a look at the anwers of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229759/ubuntu-12-10-windows-7-no-option-to-install-alongside-windows-7) question

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which windows version you have. How many partitions in your computer?.

1. If windows system partition is in some other partition other than C: drive ubuntu installer will not detect Windows OS.
2. If windows system is in C: drive. Open windows disk management and shrink C drive around 50GB and leave the 50GB disk space as unallocated(Don't format the free space).
3. If Windows disk management not allowed to shrink C: drive around 50GB then use Easeus Partition Master free tool. you can download from this link:http://download.cnet.com/Easeus-Partition-Master-Free-Edition/3000-2248_4-10863346.html
4. Now run the ubuntu installer. I hope you will get the option "Install alongside windows".
5. If you are done, Just reply it will be helpful for others and don't forget to click star.