# Cannot find Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows, partitioning

Is there a solution to this?

Gparted gives me [image]

Thanks a lot.
Best Regards.

Comment: You do not have windows installed in your PC. Install your version of windows first from the windows installation media.

Answer (score 0):

If the Ubuntu don't suggest to mount an NTFS partition, I am afraid the installation was delete your windows. If you have a back up for your windows, it time to use it.

Comment: if it is the case, and windows was deleted, how can re install it through ubuntu ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to tell me more detail about the Ubuntu you have.
But I only have a solution that you will need to delete this Ubuntu, and Install again windows, and then again Ubuntu.
I don't know to do this other wise.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Ubuntu, you selected to use the whole disk instead of installing it besides your Windows installation. Some people don't see this option for various reasons, so always be careful with what you do and understand what options you select before you proceed.

You are now left with unpartitioned space so you are safe to install Windows. Just boot your pc from your Windows installation media (CD/DVD/USB/Network/...) and use the unpartitioned space as Windows will suggest.

After the installation, you will immediately boot into your Windows and initially be unable to boot Ubuntu because Windows will overwrite your MBR and use its own boatloader that initially, doesn't see Ubuntu.
You then have the option to customize the Windows bootloader or re-install GRUB2 as bootloader so you can choose to boot Windows or Ubuntu. There are several threads on stackexchange explaining how to do both.

Comment: i have chosen the option install with windows!i haven't delete it

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows what's the means please of boot into a live session. ? i insert the CD that i have used for installation ?

Comment: Looking at your partition layout, you either give us the partition layout of the wrong disk in your system, or you have removed the Windows installation by installing Ubuntu over it. If you installed next to Windows, you should somewhere see an NTFS partition.

Comment: i have done like in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxZRjjPjic8 so i get ubuntu and i lost wondows, here is the partitions: http://imgur.com/zEQcdv4   Please, how can i get a list of choice of sys at the begining ?

Comment: You are missing a few steps in your explanation. There's a difference between your gparted images. Did you install Windows again, lost your Ubuntu startup and then fix GRUB again following that youtube vid? If so, check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/110698/add-windows-to-my-boot-menu