# Can someone help me with Windows 7 installation?

Tags: grub2, windows-7

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7. I used to initially have Windows, but after installing Ubuntu, I can't find it anywhere and have no clue what happened. Yes, I'm an idiot, because I didn't back up. Now that I got the installation for Windows and created an unallocated drive for space, I keep getting an error message saying partition on boot disk needs at least 829 megabytes of free space (I have 10GB of unallocated space). I tried using GParted, but nothing works.

I keep getting the error message:

[image]

I just need to know how to install Windows 7 on Ubuntu. No websites really explain it. Apparently I didn't notice it was using Wine this whole time. But aside from that, how can I install Windows 7 without Wine and alongside Ubuntu?

Comment: are you trying to install windows FROM Ubuntu? I mean, did you started windwos 7 installation while running Ubuntu?

Comment: yes. i was, but it kept opening wine.

Comment: no, you can not install Windows from Ubuntu. are you sure your Windows partition is lost? are you sure you dont see it in GParted?   If it really is not listed there, what could happened is that during Ubuntu installation you somehow checked the option to delete all other partitions and to install Ubuntu only..

Comment: my partition is still there. it's called OS. the thing is, i can't access it, and Ubuntu says there are no other operating systems. however, i keep getting a message from that partition saying:Unable to access “OS” No object for D-Bus interface.

Comment: Your OS still seems to be there, you probably need to add Windows to your GRUB2 configuration to make it working. Also, not sure about your 10GB partition. MS seems to think 16GB is needed for Win7 32bit, 20GB for Win7 64bit. Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/110698/add-windows-to-my-boot-menu. And when installing Windows, DON'T do that from within Ubuntu. Boot your computer with the installation disk/usb.

Comment: If you told Ubuntu's installer to use the *entire disk* instead of installing *alongside* the already installed OS (Windows), this might be a duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/286181) If Ubuntu's installed, Windows isn't, and you don't need to recover documents: [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6317) If you decide to wipe the disk and reinstall Windows and still want Ubuntu too: [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366)

Answer (score 0):

From reading your comments it seems like you are trying to install Windows second, which doesnt work. You need to boot the computer from the Windows CD then install, then reinstall Ubuntu if it overwrites the partition.

Comment: I would also check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/158319/67920

Comment: how will i be able to do it then?

Comment: At boot hit F12 then select CD (with the CD in the drive) that will start the installation process. Though please look at the above answer too, is your partition gone or can you not boot? You may be able to simple repair the MBR (Using the installation disk). Please tell us if your windows partition has been overwritten or just cannot be booted. (Also did you select to install Ubuntu alongside or Inplace of?)