# How I can add an entry for windows 10 into Grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, window

I have 2 disk on my computer; the first with Windows 10 (/dev/sda) and in the other Ubuntu(/dev/sdb).
Here some image about my disks:

[image]
[image]

Grub is installed on /dev/sdb but in Grub menu does not appear Windows 10 to start.

How I can add an entry for windows 10 into Grub?

I already tried with this, but does not works for me:
[Add windows to my boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110698/add-windows-to-my-boot-menu)

Comment: Were both disks mounted when you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: We need some more information. Windows partition? Is the partition table MSDOS or GPT? UEFI partition?

Comment: Partition table: GUID (partition for /dev/sda was autogenerated when I install windows) Is an UEFI as well.

Yes, the disks are mounted when I execute `sudo update-grub`